# PHP foreach loop key value to $value

Tags: php, html, foreach, preg-match, echo

So I have this string:

```
>Page No 1<>Page No 2<>Page No 3<
```

Where I use a regex to match each `>Page No [number]<` and put it in an array, which I then can loop through and display them: then i write $page value in my text file.

```
    $pn = '>Page No 1<>Page No 2<>Page No 3<';
    preg_match_all('/>Page No (\d+)</is', $pn, $matches);

    foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $value) {
    echo $page = '<a href="#page-'.htmlentities($value).'">' . htmlentities($value). '</a>';
    }

    $current = 'P: NAME R:';
    $PETITIONER = preg_replace('#(.*)P:(.*?)R:(.*)#is', '$2', $current);

    // Petitioner
$pj_sc_pet_dot = str_replace(array('!\s+!',':'), array(' ',''), $PETITIONER); 
$ucpj_sc_pet = ucwords(strtolower($pj_sc_pet_dot));
$pj_sc_pet_dec = htmlspecialchars_decode(trim($ucpj_sc_pet));

 $pet =  '<li class="post_petitioner">Petitioner : '.$pj_sc_pet_dec.'</li>';


    $file = 'dl/book.txt';

    $fp=fopen($file,'w+');

    $judgment = "{$page}{$pet}";
    //now, save the file
    fwrite($fp,$judgment,strlen($judgment));
```

But for some reason, I only write 1 result. I have no idea why.

Comment: You just don't see it, but they are there! (`$value` -> `htmlentities($value)`)

Comment: thank you Rizier123 how to use this

Comment: Just instead of using `$value` in the foreach loop wrap it in the function call

Comment: @Rizier123 can't he also do *$matches[$key]* in the echo statement?

Comment: @baboizk Yes, he could, but still would have to wrap it into the function call. Since `<` is the start of a html tag the browser will think now it comes a tag, which it hides from the normal output.

Comment: @Rizier123 true, thanks for explaining

Answer (score 0):

```
            foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $value) {

        $current = 'P: NAME R:';
        $PETITIONER = preg_replace('#(.*)P:(.*?)R:(.*)#is', '$2', $current);

        // Petitioner
    $pj_sc_pet_dot = str_replace(array('!\s+!',':'), array(' ',''), $PETITIONER); 
    $ucpj_sc_pet = ucwords(strtolower($pj_sc_pet_dot));
    $pj_sc_pet_dec = htmlspecialchars_decode(trim($ucpj_sc_pet));

     $pet =  '<li class="post_petitioner">Petitioner : '.$pj_sc_pet_dec.'</li>';


$pn = '>Page No 1<>Page No 2<>Page No 3<';
        preg_match_all('/>Page No (\d+)</is', $pn, $matches);

foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $value) {
$page .= '<a href="#page-'.htmlentities($value).'">' . htmlentities($value). '</a>';

$pag ='
<li class="post_page-no">Page No : '.$page.'</li>
</ul></div></div> <!-- The Judgment Information -->
';


        $file = 'dl/book.txt';

        $fp=fopen($file,'w+');

        $judgment = "{$page}{$pet}";
    }
        //now, save the file
        fwrite($fp,$judgment,strlen($judgment));
```

Comment: Thank you Rizier123 i think this is correct Answer or not